# How to modify my code - How to loop up to nth row of a DataTable?

Tags: c#, for-loop

My current code loops through all the rows of particular column of a DataTable object. I want it to loop only up to the 2nd last position. How do I do it ?

I know this can be done by a for loop instead of my foreach. but, I don't know how to get number of rows and then iterate row by row based on an index. Thats where i need help.

```
    public void Main()
    {
        OleDbDataAdapter oleDA = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn col = null;
        DataRow row = null;
        string strCols = null;

        oleDA.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["ExecuteSQLTask_ResultSet"].Value);
        col = dt.Columns["AColumInDataTable"];

        foreach (DataRow row_ in dt.Rows)
        {
            row = row_;
            strCols = strCols + row[col.Ordinal].ToString() + ", ";
        }

        strCols = strCols.Substring(0, strCols.Length - 2);

        MessageBox.Show("Rows of a column contain - " + strCols);

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

Comment: You used the tag `for-loop`.  That should be a hint. :-)

Comment: @LarsTech - yes, I know that. But, I don't know how to get number of rows and then iterate row by row based on an index. Thats where i need help.

Comment: You can directly access the nth row without looping if this is what you mean. dt.Rows [n-1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your `foreach` to

```
for(int i=0; i<dt.Rows.Count-1;i++)
{
   var row = dt.Rows[i]
   strCols += row[col.Ordinal].ToString() + ", ";
}
```

As per your edit, you get the number of Rows using `dt.Rows.Count`.  To get the second to last row, use `dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count-2]`

Also note you can use `+=` on your string

Answer (score 2):

```
    for (int loop = 0; loop <= dt.Rows.Count - 2; loop++)
    {
        row = dt.Rows[loop];
        //your code
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is using Linq, may not be as fast as for loop:

```
string strCols = "";
dt.AsEnumerable().Take(dt.Rows.Count-2)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(r=> strCols += "," + r.Field<string>(col.Ordinal));
```

Using `string.Join()` method:

```
var results = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .Take(dt.Rows.Count-2)
                .Select(r=>r.Field<string>(col.Ordinal)).ToArray();
string strCols = string.Join(",", results);
```

Comment: Sure, that is true !!